# Weird H Bridge measurements: BJTs of Mosfets?

Tags: bjt, h-bridge, short-circuit

I'm trying to use the `H bridge` on the main board of a robot whose microcontroller I removed.

It is connected to a small motor and contains 4 SMDs named `5CW` and `6CW`. After painstakingly soldering small copper cables to the control traces and powering it at `6V`, the current limit kicked in. It actually draws around `1.4V` (looks like the positive rail is connected through `2 diodes` to the negative).

Now the board contains other but few components (`3 leds`, couple of resistors and `2 BJTs`) so I can't be sure what causes this "short" circuit. Using diode measurement on the `Vcc-Ground` gives 570 and `G-Vcc` 474.

**This is the H bridge diagram**:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHycr6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Diode measurements for the H bridge**:

```
Q1:  BC: 936, CB: 450   BE: 1260, EB: 450    CE: 880, EC: 565
Q2:  BC: 933, CB: 428   BE: 1263, EB: 448    CE: 884, EC: 564
Q3:  BC: 457, CB: 920   BE: 456,  EB: 1245   CE: 568, EC: 881
Q4:  BC: 456, CB: 918   BE: 456,  EB: 1243   CE: 568, EC: 880
```

From the `BC` and `BE` measurements I thought these were `BJTs` (Q1, Q2 `PNP` and Q3,Q4 `NPN`). But the `CE` and `EC` measurements are weird. Perhaps they are correct for `mosfets`?

**Note**:

1. There are two `H bridges` including this one that have the same measurements so I find it hard to believe that every bridge and `BJT` was burned. I believe only the original microcontroller, which I removed, suffered the burn.
2. While testing `Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4` the motor was disconnected and as such all collectors are not part of any circuit except that of the bridge. Also all the gates are disconnected.
3. My multimeter just shows a value when measuring diodes. I never understood what it meant (drop voltage?).

It's hard to do any diagnostic on such a board. Nevertheless, with this data, does the H bridge behave as it should measurement-wise?

Comment: Why do you think the MCU, and not the bridge components would  have been damaged?

Comment: Because the motor was not active and the voltage I applied should be within limits of the bjts(if they are bjts). I applied 8v instead of 6.          The gates are protected with resistors and so couldn't have been burned.

Comment: The MCU burned because the guy who designed the board did not include a voltage regulator on this expensive robot. He figured the 6v from 4 batteries are just barely under the absolute ratings of the mcu and so should work fine.